# A NP-complete problem with difficult NP membership proof

Tags: np-complete, np

A proof of $\mathsf{NP}$-completeness for a decision problem requires two things:

- $\mathsf{NP}$ membership;
- $\mathsf{NP}$-hardness.

It is often the case that the $\mathsf{NP}$-hardness part is the most difficult to prove, and it is not rare that some papers completely omit the $\mathsf{NP}$ membership part.

What I would like to ask is: is there a $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problem such that its $\mathsf{NP}$ membership via certificate existence is at least as difficult to prove than its $\mathsf{NP}$-hardness. For example, a [primality certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate) is not quite intuitive to find (but the primality decision problem is in $\mathsf{P}$, so it is not $\mathsf{NP}$-complete unless $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$).

Comment: I think I've seen problems like this, but I'm having a hard time remembering specifics.  I think it was a problem over the integers, and there was a non-trivial theorem that if any solution exists (i.e., any integer exists that solves the problem), then there exists a solution of polynomial size (i.e., there exists a solution where all the integers in the solution have bit-length that is polynomial in the input length).